# How to display AWS autoscaling group name using ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, ansible-2.x, aws-auto-scaling

I was writing Ansible playbook to display the auto scaling group of AWS based on tags and below is my playbook.

```
- name: Find the green asg with matching tags
  ec2_asg_info:
    tags:
      service_name: cps_wallet
      Environment: "{{ name_env }}"
      service_state: green
  register: asgs_payment

- name: Show the ASG Payment name
  debug: 
    msg: "{{ asgs_payment.results[0].auto_scaling_group_name}}"

- set_fact:
    asg_payment_name: "{{ asgs_payment.results[0].auto_scaling_group_name}}"
```

I was running it on Jenkins and I was getting error

`fatal: [127.0.18.34]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: list object has no element 0\n\nThe error appears to be in '/opt/software/jenkins/workspace/payment-react-ui/srv/payment-ui-110/payment-ui/roles/inspect/tasks/cps_green_deploy.yml': line 9, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Show the ASG Payment name\n ^ here\n"}`

I thought the result doesn't have any asg name so i updated the above code as

```
- name: Find the green asg with matching tags
  ec2_asg_info:
    tags:
      service_name: cps_wallet
      Environment: "{{ name_env }}"
      service_state: green
  register: asgs_payment

- name: Show the ASG Payment name
  debug:
    msg: "{{ asgs_payment}}"

- set_fact:
    asg_payment_name: "{{ asgs_payment}}"
```

It didn't give me any error, but the result was empty.

```
"msg": { "changed": false,  "failed": false,  "results": [] }
```

I do have tags added in my ASG as you can see below. And there is no other asg with same tags
[Tags image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvAcL.jpg)

The same playbook works like a charm for my other applications

Comment: Do you have set the name_env variables, with which value ? Which ansible version do you use?

Comment: I was passing name_env as jenkins parameter i even tried adding it directly doesn't work! Ansible version is ansible 2.9.23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me

```
- name: Display Auto Scaling group name
  ec2_asg_info:
    region: us-east-1
    name: my-asg
  register: asg_info

- debug:
    msg: "Auto Scaling group name: {{ asg_info.auto_scaling_groups[0].name }}"
```

EDIT:

here is a template of playbook

```
---
- name: Display Auto Scaling group of AWS instance
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Get instance information
      ec2_instance_info:
        region: us-east-1
        filters:
          "tag:Name": "my-instance"
      register: instance_info

    - name: Get Auto Scaling group information
      ec2_asg_info:
        region: us-east-1
        name: "{{ instance_info.instances[0].asg_name }}"
      register: asg_info

    - name: Display Auto Scaling group name
      debug:
        msg: "Auto Scaling group name: {{ asg_info.auto_scaling_groups[0].name }}"
```

the **ec2_instance_info** module is used to retrieve information about the instance with the tag Name set to **"my-instance"** in the us-east-1 region. The **ec2_asg_info** module is then used to retrieve information about the Auto Scaling group that the instance belongs to, using the **asg_name** attribute of the instance. Finally, the debug module is used to display the name of the Auto Scaling group.

You can modify this

Comment: I'm getting this now {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'auto_scaling_groups'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/opt/software/jenkins/workspace/react-ui/srv/payment-ui-141/wps-payment-ui/roles/inspect/tasks/cps_green_deploy.yml': line 11, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- debug:\n  ^ here\n"}

Comment: Great! Now they were able to display! Thanks alot. I spent like hours looking into this. I did found the tag of instance

Answer (score 1):

- name: Get information about Auto Scaling group
  ec2_asg_facts:
  region: "{{ region }}"
  register: asg_facts
- name: Display Auto Scaling group name
  debug:
  msg: "The Auto Scaling group name is {{ asg_facts.autoscaling_groups[0].name }}"

Comment: I tried this still the result is empty